# How to assign a value to simulation time in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I have a file with transactions, each has a time when it occurred.
I want to run a SystemVerilog simulation, and "play" each transaction on its time

However, I don't want to actually wait the clock cycles between the transactions. 
Instead I want to assign transaction time (from the file) to the SystemVerilog simulation time (assignment should occur within 0 time).

Is it possible to advance System Verilog simulation time this way ?
If so - how ?

Simplified version of the file :

```
TIME (ns)    |   TRANSACTION DATA   
    1        |     0x1, 0x2, 0x3
    5        |     0x4, 0x5, 0x6
   200       |     0xa, 0xb, 0xc
  10000      |     0xd, 0xe, 0xf
```

Thanks.
Roi.

Comment: It would really help to show a simplified version of what your file looks like, and how you want the transaction applied as stimulus.

Comment: Some things that need explaining: are the transactions ordered in time within the file? How much time does each transaction take, and is there overlap between transactions. These things make a difference on how you set up the process to execute each transaction.

Comment: 1. Yes - transactions in the file are ordered in time.

Comment: 2. For simplicity - each transaction takes 1 clock cycle and there is no overlap between transactions.

Comment: Another thing to note - the 1st transaction may occur at time 1ns, and 2nd transaction may occur 10000ns later. So I want to change simulation time from 1ns to 10001ns without actually waiting those clock cycles.

Answer (score 1):

In an event-driven simulation language. such as SystemVerilog, time is a global value shared by all processes. You cannot set it—you can only observe it's current value.

The way an event-driven simulation works, it works in a loop processing a queue of events at the current time until the queue is empty. Only then does it advance time to the next scheduled event at a future time. So what you can do is have a process block waiting for some time in the future.

SystemVerilog does not provide a way of scheduling something for a particular time, but if you observe the current time, you can subtract that the time from the time in the future you want, the block for that amount of time.

Since your transactions do not overlap, you can read the file one line at a time and wait for the specified time. You read the first line at time 0 and wait for 1-$realtime. Then execute the transaction. When it is done, you read the second line and wait for 5-$realtime. This can be done in a loop until reaching the end-of-file.